# working with negative sign restriction in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am new in optimization. I want to solve a maximization problem using simplex method whose one of the decision variable is negative sign constraint. I know how to process for positive sign constraint, but have no idea about negative.

My optimization problem is $$\text{max} \hspace{2mm} P=10x-y+6z \\ s.t.\hspace{5mm} 2x+5y+2z=8\\ 4x-y \leq 6 \\y+z \geq2\\x\geq0,y\leq0,z-\text{unrestricted}
$$
So, it will be better if you can write the standard form of the given maximization problem. Thanks,

Comment: Notice that $y\leq0$ is equivalent to $-y\geq 0$.

Comment: so can we replace $y$ by $-y$ in the objective function and constraint?

Comment: Yes, and you replace $y\leq 0$ by $y \geq 0$

Comment: So my objective function and constraints looks like  $$\text{max} \hspace{2mm} P=10x+y+6z \\ s.t.\hspace{5mm} 2x-5y+2z=8\\ 4x+y \leq 6 \\-y+z \geq2\\x\geq0,-y\leq 0 (y \geq 0),z-\text{unrestricted}
$$

Comment: Look like what ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the comment. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, that´t right. Now have to replace z by two other variables. $z=z^+-z^-$ with $z^+,z^-\geq 0$. Therefore you have 4 non-negative variables.

Comment: Yes, I know about the unrestricted variables. I got the point and thanks a lot....

Comment: That´s fine. You´re welcome.

Comment: What about the sensitivity analysis of first constraint after getting the final optimal tableau? Do I need to change to the original $y$ or I can work with the new $y$?